# exiting from while true loop using EOFError dose not work exactly as expected

Tags: python, while-loop, try-catch

I am trying to solve a simple problem in python and this problem I'm using while true loop and to exit this loop I'm using EOFError or in the terminal using control + D (in Linux or mac, Ctrl + z + enter in windows)

the problem is like this, the user enter keep entering inputs and when he wants to stop, he just uses cntrol+d in Linux or mac or control+z+entre  in windows

in windows it works, but in Linux it keeps giving the input and the result

here is my code

```
def main():
    menu = {
        "Baja Taco": 4.00,
        "Burrito": 7.50,
        "Bowl": 8.50,
        "Nachos": 11.00,
        "Quesadilla": 8.50,
        "Super Burrito": 8.50,
        "Super Quesadilla": 9.50,
        "Taco": 3.00,
        "Tortilla Salad": 8.00
    }
    total_order = 0
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = str(input("Item: "))
            the_input = user_input.title()
        except EOFError:
            print(f"Total: ${round(total_order,1)}", end='\n')
            break
        else:
            for key, value in menu.items():
                if the_input == key:
                    total_order = total_order + value


if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

and i use another approch

```
def main():
    menu = {
        "baja taco": 4.00,
        "burrito": 7.50,
        "bowl": 8.50,
        "nachos": 11.00,
        "quesadilla": 8.50,
        "super burrito": 8.50,
        "super quesadilla": 9.50,
        "taco": 3.00,
        "tortilla salad": 8.00
    }

    items = []
    x = 0
    try:
        while True:
            items.append(input("Item: "))
    except EOFError:
            for item in items:
                if item in menu:
                    x = x + menu[item]
            print(f"Total: ${round(x,1)}", end='\n')
```

here is the input / output that i have and how it suppose it work

```
-----
in linux 
input :
Item: taco
Item: taco
Item: Total: $6.00 # -----> In Linux when I hit control+d it give me item and total 
It should give me only the total  
------
in windows
Item: taco 
Item: taco
Item: taco
Item: ^Z
Total: $9.00
```

is there a way to make it give me only the total when I use the EOFError?

Comment: There's no reason to use a `for` loop to find a key in a dictionary. Just use `menu.get(user_input, 0)`

Comment: I tried your first script on Linux and MacOS and it worked in both.

Comment: I'm using the vs. code that work on line and it always give me the same error  when I want to exit using control d it print `Item: Total: $6.00` but it suppose to print only `Total: $6.00`

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the VS Code terminal emulator. Run it from a regular terminal window.

Comment: in windows it works, that's why I'm stuck thank you very much

Comment: I can't explain why it only fails on Linux. But the problem isn't with your script, it's with the terminal emulator.

Comment: thank you very much and thanx for that hint `menu.get(user_input, 0)`

Comment: Wait, the problem is that you see `Item: Total: $6.00 ` without a newline in linux? That's what's supposed to happen. The `Item: ` part is the prompt before the ctrl-d and the `Total ...` is the next print. You could add your own newline before `Total`. Windows is bizarrely adding a newline on ctrl-z. Can't imagine why. It shouldn't do that. Or maybe that's okay on windows... I don't know the full semantics of ctrl-z.

Comment: I try that but its like I print item: and a new line doesn't like when I hit control do it automatically give only the answer, so that's what I want to give me only the total as the answer not the input () and the result

Answer (score 1):

No bug here. In the Linux/Mac terminal world, `ctrl` masks all but the first 5 bits of the "controlled" character and sends that to the server. For `ctrl-d`, that's `ord("d") & 0x1f` or `4`. Looking in the ASCII chart, that's End of Transmission. A single character is sent and nothing is echoed back to the screen. Python converts that to an `EOFError` exception. Your code prints `"Total.."`. Since the terminal has not received any other data, especially not a newline, it continues right where the cursor was when you hit `ctrl-d`.

Windows is different. Notice that you had to do `ctrl-v\n` - that is, press the enter key. That `enter` causes the terminal to advance to the next line. That's the difference.

You'll need to write some platform dependent code to get the same effect on both types of systems. But its pretty easy.

```
import platform

def platform_dependent_newline():
    """Print a newline on non-Windows systems. Useful when catching
    stdin EOF where Windows provides the newline but others don't."""
    if platform.system() != "Windows"
        print()
```

Comment: thank you for this I have never seen this before, I'm trying to solve this problem [link](https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/3/taqueria/), in their vs. code and even with your solution, it did work, thank you very much for this information, mybe there is a pb with the vs code thank again